# Color with Table Environment

Tags: tables, floats, color

Please have a look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{yellow!20}{
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Female}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Male}\tabularnewline                                   
\midrule
1 year- 2 years&2 (50\%)&2 (13.33\%)\tabularnewline
2 years - 3 years&0 (0\%)&4 (26.67\%)\tabularnewline
3 years +&1 (25\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
6 months- 1 year&1 (25\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
Less than 6 months&0 (0\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

I don't get a output from the above code. But if comment out `Table` environment that is I put the `Tabular` environment in the `colorbox` then it works. My objective is to color the entire table but I want to color the  `Table` environment. This is because I am creating table with `latex` function from `Hmisc` package from `R` which automatically creates the `Table` environment. I know I could use `xtable` package with `floating=False` option but I need to use `latex` function for other purposes.

I also understand I am not supposed to ask `R` questions here but since the latex related problem arose due to use of certain R package, if any one could suggest a workaround with R tables to created colored background in latex that would be quite helpful.

Comment: You cannot put a float such as `table` inside a `\colorbox` which is static.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a float such as `table` inside a `\colorbox` which is static. Go the other way around and use `\colorbox` inside `table`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\colorbox{yellow!20}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Female}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Male}\tabularnewline                                   
\midrule
1 year- 2 years&2 (50\%)&2 (13.33\%)\tabularnewline
2 years - 3 years&0 (0\%)&4 (26.67\%)\tabularnewline
3 years +&1 (25\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
6 months- 1 year&1 (25\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
Less than 6 months&0 (0\%)&3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd suggest you to use [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to properly format and align your data.

Comment: Hello Gonazalo, my problem is that my latex tables are autogenerated in R, therefore only way to put the colorbox is manually or using some postprocessing code. Is there any other way to preprocess, that is putting other latex functions before the Table environment to make the color work?

Comment: @RushadFaridi And do you want to keep the tables as floating objects or can you restrict/suppress flotation?

Comment: I don't mind either way as long as the color works.

Comment: @RushadFaridi The problem then is how to capture the width of the table. I can think on a solution, but it will apply the background color to the entire `\textwidth`, not just to the `tabular`. Would this be useful for you or do you want to restrict the color just to the width of the tabular material?

Comment: Tabular material would be good but little bit more than that won't hurt I guess. But if it the whole width of text area then its a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, without the table environment — replaced with `center`. In case you still want a caption, I used the `captionof` command, supplied by the `capt-of` and the `caption` package. Don't forget `%` just before `\begin{tabular}` and just after `\end{tabular}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
%
\begin{center}
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
  \vskip-\topsep%
  \captionof{table}{Sexology}
  \smallskip%
  \colorbox{Yellow1!15}{%
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
      \toprule
                         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{HotPink1}Female} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{DodgerBlue2}Male}\tabularnewline
      \midrule
      1 year--2 years & 2 (50\%) & 2 (13.33\%)\tabularnewline
      2 years--3 years & 0 (0\%) & 4 (26.67\%)\tabularnewline
      3 years + & 1 (25\%) & 3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
      6 months--1 year & 1 (25\%) & 3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
      Less than 6 months & 0 (0\%) & 3 (20\%)\tabularnewline
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{center}%
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need a solution with `Table` environment not just `Tabular`.

Comment: What for do you want a table environment? Ìf it is only to be able to cross-reference it? You can do it with `\captionof{table}. If you really want to let it float (that is the only difference with ``\captionof`, as far as I know), I'm sorry, I don't know how to do it, and I'm afraid it's not possible. Or you will have to modify the code for tabular, adding `>{\columncolor{yellow!80!}` before each qualifier in the tabular preamble.

Comment: Thanks Bernard for your response. Can anybody else suggest anything or I should post the question in the R forum?

Comment: I'm not sure of what is a **T**able environment here (with a capital T). Is it some spcoal environment defined by R? If it is, yes, you could try to post onthe R forum. If you mean only an ordinary table environment, why do you want to have one, since you answered to @Gonzalo Medina you didn't mind whether  your table would be floating or not?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I just meant the regular table environment. I don't mind the table to be floating or not as long as it comes out of R code. But the problem is that the Code I am using generates table environment and I don't find any work around to that.

Comment: Do you have that many tables? It wouldn't be  too long to slighly modify the code if they're not too many.

Comment: Unfortunately there are quite a few :-(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25675/discussion-between-bernard-and-rushad-faridi).

Comment: Yes, we surely can.